# Using sequences to build an array row in expl3

Tags: arrays, expl3

The following code compiles, but does not do what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\attribute}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\constant}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \extrelationrow { m m } {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \shepi_vals {,} {#2}
  \seq_pop_right:NN \shepi_vals \shepi_last
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \shepi_vals {#1{##1}} % <=====
  %\seq_map_inline:Nn \shepi_vals {#1{##1} & }
  #1{\shepi_last}
  \\
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{llll}
  \extrelationrow{\attribute}{A,B,C,D}
  \extrelationrow{\constant}{e,f,g,h}
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

If you comment the marked line with the commented one, then compilation fails with the following surprising (at least for me) error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \shepi_last 

l.21   \extrelationrow{\attribute}{A,B,C,D}
```

If I accumulate the `#1{##1}` values in some auxiliary list and use `seq_use:Nn`, it works but I have to declare this auxiliary list outside of the function and use `seq_clear:N`. I believe that accumulating takes more resources and is unnecessary here. Anyway I would like to understand why my variable `\shepi_last` disappears when I add an `&` on the above line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\seq_map_inline:Nn` cannot straddle alignment cells.

You can process the sequence to adorn each item with `\seq_set_map:NNn` and then use `\seq_use:Nn`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\attribute}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\constant}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_shepi_vals_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_shepi_vals_out_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \extrelationrow { m m }
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_shepi_vals_in_seq {,} {#2}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_shepi_vals_out_seq \l_shepi_vals_in_seq { \exp_not:n { #1{##1} } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_shepi_vals_out_seq { & }
  \\
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{llll}
  \extrelationrow{\attribute}{A,B,C,D}
  \extrelationrow{\constant}{e,f,g,h}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Please, note the proper naming of variables, which should have a prefix and a suffix, in this case `l_` (local) and `_seq` (sequence).

[image]

Differently from `\seq_map_inline:Nn`, `\seq_use:Nn` delivers its result in one swoop, so it can be used in an alignment cell. It adds the tokens in the second argument only *between* items, so no pop is necessary.

For technical reason, the third argument to `\seq_set_map:NNn` is fully expanded, so `\exp_not:n` has to be used.

Comment: I knew that I would get valuable advice in addition to a solution to my problem. My bad for not checking the l3candidates interface. Thank you very much for your help! Latex3 is actually changing my life, I love it! :-)

Comment: As a side question, is there any reason you "declare" the two sequences outside of the command? The code works without these two lines but maybe there is a performance argument ongoing here?

Comment: @FabianPijcke It's good programming style to declare the variables we're going to use. For implementation reasons using undeclared token list or sequence variables works, but it's a fact one shouldn't rely upon.